# Is there any web browser for android with "File System Access API"?

Tags: file-management, web-browser, api, chromium

Chromium based android browsers currently don't have the support for "File System Access API" and Firefox mobile also doesn't have the support.

I have checked caniuse.com where it shows some browsers about the support for this API.
But I don't know if there are any browsers that supports it and are not in caniuse.com

I would also be interested in any experimental version of browser that has this API. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The File System Access API is currently not supported on Android. The feature bug to star is https://crbug.com/1011535. Starring a bug means you will be updated when progress is being made. Meanwhile, I recommend the [browser-fs-access](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/browser-fs-access) library as a solution that automatically falls back to an alternative implementation when the File System Access API isn’t supported.